# postgresql some and all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I'm trying to get two seperate values. Invoices that have ALL of their payments made and invoices that have SOME of their payments made.
This is a rails app so

```
Invoices has_many :payments
```

Payments are either paid:true or paid:false.
So on my first call I want to get the invoice id's of those invoices that have all payments made. I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (invoices.id) FROM "invoices" join payments on payments.invoice_id = invoices.id WHERE "invoices"."payer_id" = 1 AND (payments.paid = ALL(array[true]))
```

Unfortunately this returns a row for an invoice even if 2 out of 3 are paid:true

The next call is to get invoices where some are paid:true and some are paid:false. For this I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (invoices.id) FROM "invoices" join payments on payments.invoice_id = invoices.id WHERE "invoices"."payer_id" = 1 AND (payments.paid = SOME(array[true]) AND payments.paid = SOME(array[false]))
```

But this doesn't return a row even if some of the payments from that invoice are paid while others aren't.

Am I using ALL and SOME correctly? Or is there another way to make this call? Seems like a fairly straightforward call so I'm sure there's some way to do it. Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`=ALL (array[...])` means *equal to all elements of the array*, and when the array has only one element it's equivalent to a simple equality test.

So `payments.paid = ALL(array[true])` is equivalent to `payments.paid = true`.

And by a similar logic, `payments.paid = SOME(array[false])` is equivalent to `payments.paid = false`.

Arrays and ALL/SOME don't seem to be needed or desirable with this query. It may be expressed like this:

"Find invoices for which there's no corresponding payment with paid=false"

```
select distinct I.id
from invoices I
where payer_id=1
and not exists (select 1 FROM payments P WHERE P.invoice_id=I.id AND P.paid=false);
```

A different way to express it:

"Find invoices for which the count of payments is equal to the count of payments with p.paid=true (meaning payments are all made)"

```
select I.id
from invoices I join payments P on (I.id=P.invoice_id)
group by I.id
having sum(P.paid::int)=count(*);
```

`p.paid::int` evaluates to 1 when p.paid is true, and to 0 when p.paid is false

For the other query, you can play with the `having` clause.
For exemple `having sum(P.paid::int)<count(*)` will keep only the invoices for which the number of paid payments is less than the number of payments for this invoice, which should mean they're not entirely paid.

Comment: Ahh perfect, thank you I didn't think of having. Switching from MySql to PG and I'm finding it difficult. Stupid heroku.